# Are there some paid or free Rails3 "ninja" screencasts/tutorials?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Things like railstutorial.org are too simple. I am looking for some best practices, diving into Rails core, developing gems for rails etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you looked at [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/)? IMO it's the best of the free ones. [PeepCode](http://peepcode.com/screencasts) has really good pay screencasts, but they're more limited in scope, and they're not generally ninja-level.

I'll add a book, [Crafting Rails Applications](http://pragprog.com/book/jvrails/crafting-rails-applications), because it *is* ninja-level, and pretty fun. Not a screencast, but IMO, you just can't put ninja-level stuff into a screencast--the info necessary is too complex.

Comment: Also [ASCIIcasts](http://www.asciicasts.com), if you prefer reading to watching videos.

Comment: Thanks. Peepcode is pretty nice, but Rails content is old there.

Answer (score 1):

[Peepcode](http://peepcode.com/) and [Tekpub](http://tekpub.com/productions/rails3) both have good intro videos series. Railscasts does 1 off videos as mentioned by Dave Newton. I don't think you'll get videos in series format above and beyond intro - it's just too vague. Instead, you'll have to resort to videos "per need" (ie, railscasts)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Rails for Zombies](http://railsforzombies.org/)

Answer (score -1):

Here is a tutorial I found about ninjas:
http://www.wikihow.com/Be-a-Ninja

This site is actually about programmers though, maybe you wanted to ask how to be a programmer?